# Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDonecode prevents the login mask of an SQL query in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, authentication

I have an SQL query in Excel. After the query a message should appear. This works well as an existing user, but for new users the password query is hidden.

I was looking for an alternative to Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone but couldn't find a solution. The Excel login mask is always not displayed.

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
MsgBox "The new data has been imported.", , "Import done"

How can I get Excel to wait for the end of the query and get the login displayed before (if I have never entered the password as a new user)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this not the solution you're looking for, but I don't think it exists I'm afraid. Embedded query objects in Excel are horrible to work with, and they expect you to be using Active Directory for your SQL Server password, hence the exceptionally poor handling of the "login" popup box.

My advice would be to move away from embedded workbook tables / queries and script out your queries using an ADODB connection, purely in VBA.

If the user's password is a simple username / password combo, then you can read it from a cell in your sheet before you send the query to the server.

If the login is based on Active Directory, then the user doesn't need to enter their password at all, ADODB will just log them on automatically.

Here's my simple SQL function I use to query SQL Server databases using ADODB. The long string in the middle after "conn.open" is the connection string. In that, replace "DatabaseHostName" with the Host name of your DB, and "DatabaseName" with the name of the DB you want to query by default:

```
Sub ReadSQL(SQLQuery As String, DestinationRecordSet As Object)
Dim conn As Object
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set DestinationRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=DatabaseHostName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
conn.CommandTimeout = 0
Set DestinationRecordSet = conn.Execute(SQLQuery)
End Sub
```

then I call it like this:

```
Sub GetData()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim OutputRecordSet As Object
Dim SQLQuery As String

SQLQuery = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.SomeTable"

ReadSQL SQLQuery, OutputRecordSet

'Clear output sheet'
wb.Sheets("Output").Cells.ClearContents

'Write Headers from query in row 1'
For x = 0 To OutputRecordSet.Fields.Count - 1
    wb.Sheets("Output").Cells(1, x + 1).Value = OutputRecordSet.Fields(x).Name
Next x

'Copy the data from the query to the worksheet, under the headers'
wb.Sheets("Output").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset OutputRecordSet

End Sub
```

When I call my "ReadSQL" sub from this sub, by default it waits until the query is complete before doing anything else.

Again I would strongly recommend active directory logins for your DB, then you never have to worry about passwords, but If you wanted to embed a user's password into the connection string, you could, or you could build the connection string based on something the user entered, or had entered into a cell in the workbook.

In any case, you will find once you move away from Excel's embedded tables which work with the dreaded "Refresh All" button, things will become much easier to control, and your queries will run about 10 times faster.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I found a workaround first.

The data is no longer updated when the table is opened. Now there is a button for first use (without application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone) and a second button for users with stored access data (more detailed and with Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone).

Comment: A fine solution indeed. You may find your users are happy with this and your button will remain in use for years without issue. I would still encourage you to experiment with ADODB connections and queries instead of Excel tables though, once you start using them you will never go back.